# How to keep player rotated toward a sphere when within a certain radius?

Tags: unity, c#

In my game the player can fly to multiple spheres, I want to make it so that when the player gets within a certain distance of the sphere, (maybe using a bigger is trigger sphere collider around it?) their feet will stay pointing towards the sphere until they leave the radius, (maybe using a quaternion?) then if they get within the radius of a different sphere, their feet will point towards that too. How can I make this work? I don't know too much about c#, so any example code would help a lot too!

Comment: Can you show us the player movement code you have so far, so we can suggest solutions that will work with that?

Comment: I don't have much so far, I just want to make the bottom of an object always point towards a sphere, without restricting rotation on other axes. any solution that automatically adjusts the rotation towards the sphere when within the radius should work

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update () {

...

transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardAxis, upAxis.z,);
}
```

this worked! although it made the camera jittery so i'll have to figure out rotation with rigidbody physics